# Как можно из бд (ajax) вывести javascript массив?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

ув. знатоки помогите вывести записи из базы данных на страницу в Javascript массив, и что бы он обновлялся через ajax.
Массив нужен такого вида:

```
playlist_sm = [
['Форсаж 4', '05-02-2020 19:00','ссылка на видео'],
['Форсаж 5', '05-02-2020 21:20','ссылка на видео']
];
```

В базе данных такие поля, (name,datatime,curl).
Вот так пытался собрать массив. Но он получается не в таком виде.

```
$sql = 'SELECT name,datatime,curl FROM `films`';
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$json = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$json[] = [ 
        '0' => $row['name'],
        '1' => $row['datatime'],
        '2' => $row['curl'],
    ];
 //$json[] = $row;
}
die(''.json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE).'');
```

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Обязательно поможем, Вы только сначала покажите, что пробовали, что старались делать. Просто так за Вас задачу никто делать не будет.

Comment: Спасибо большое за отзывчивость. Сейчас от редактирую пост. Укажу что пытался сделать но массив не в таком виде получался...

Comment: уберите эти `'0' ,'1', '2'` будет в таком

Comment: или просто `$result = $mysqli->fetch_all(); die(json_encode($result));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема видимо в том, что вы ключи результирующего массива задаете в виде строк, поэтому на выходе получаете не массив, а объект. Исправьте ключи на числовые значения `0 => ..., 1 => ...`, или вообще уберите их `[ $row['name'], .... ]` и получите массив.
Но в данном случае проще всего вообще воспользоваться методов `fetch_all()` и получить нужный результат:

```
 $sql = 'SELECT name,datatime,curl FROM `films`';
 $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
 if($result){
     $data = $mysqli->fetch_all($result);

     header("Content-type: application/json");
     echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
     exit;
 }
```

Comment: Спасибо, стиль теперь получился такой как надо только теперь нужно как то его через ajax ловить и еще дать ему имя playlist_sm..

Comment: @ДенисМилюков Почему именно через `ajax`? Вы же можете и так передать данные в `javascript`, или Вы изначально вызов в БД вызываете через `ajax`?

Comment: Через ajax потому что нужно будет обновлять массив.

Comment: Ну или хотя бы просто с парсить массив в js.

Comment: По пробовал вот так:
$.getJSON('playlist.json', function (data) {
    window.playlist = data;
    console.log(playlist);
});